# Extensão do Visual Studio Code: "Code Runner" não compila C

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gcc, mingw

Estou tentando rodar um código em **C** no **Visual Studio Code** com a extensão **Code Runner** mas não estou conseguindo. Já instalei o **MinGW** corretamente, consigo verificar ele no **cmd** via

```
g++ --version
```

Mas continuo sem conseguir fazer rodar C no VSCode. Eu sei que o VS não é o mais indicado mas queria centralizar meus trabalhos em um único editor.

A mensagem que aparece quando tento rodar é a seguinte:

```
[Running] cd "c:\Users\henrique\Documents\_minhas-coisas\_Faculdade\TesteVSCode\C\" &&
             gcc first.c -o first && 
             "c:\Users\henrique\Documents\_minhas-coisas\_Faculdade\TesteVSCode\C\"first
             'gcc' n�o � reconhecido como um comando interno
             ou externo, um programa oper�vel ou um arquivo em lotes.

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.188 seconds
```

O `First` é o nome do `arquivo.c`

Comment: Tente com a extensão c/c++  esse plugin ... na documentação é indicado ele em vez do core runner. tentei no linux com gcc e funcionou de boas.

Answer (score 0):

Crie uma variável de ambiente no `PATH` com o caminho para o gcc. O PATH é uma variável do sistema usada pelo sistema operacional para localizar executáveis que serão utilizados por linha de comando.

**Seguem as instruções:**

<kbd>Sistema</kbd>  → <kbd>Config. Avançadas do Sistema</kbd>  → <kbd>Variaveis de Ambiente</kbd> → <kbd>Adicionar no path a variável em questão</kbd>

Comment: Alterei e só mudou o erro... Agora ele aponta que não pode abrir o arquivo por falta de permissão.

[Running] cd "c:\Users\henrique\Documents\_minhas-coisas\_Faculdade\TesteVSCode\C\" && gcc first.c -o first && "c:\Users\henrique\Documents\_minhas-coisas\_Faculdade\TesteVSCode\C\"first
C:/mingw-w64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file first.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.193 seconds

Comment: já tentou executar como administrador?

Comment: Não tinha tentado, mas tentei agora e o arquivo só da que parou de funcionar. Até criei um novo arquivo pra ver se era com aqueles o problema mas continua o mesmo aviso, sem permissão.